# Different between django object.related.id and object.related_id

Tags: django

Can someone tell me the difference between object.relation.id and object.relation_id when using the django ORM.

Answer (score 1):

```
object.related.id
```

it first fetches the related object and then takes the ID

```
object.related_id
```

gets the id from foreign key column.

so `object.related_id` is cheaper

Answer (score 0):

`object.relation.id` will retrieve (if not already) `relation` model instance from database, and then return value of `id` field.

`object.relation_id` will not do any additional query to database, as `relation_id` is stored in `object` model instance level.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you operate a shop for PCs and have your products structured like this:

```
#models.py

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        Manufacturer,
        related_name='products',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

We'll put one manufacturer and two products into the database:

```
acme = Manufacturer.objects.create(name='Acme')
laptop = Product.objects.create(name='Laptop', manufacturer=acme)
keyboard = Product.objects.create(name='Keyboard') # it's a no name product
```

And now comes the interesting part:

```
# the following returns the value for the column manufacturer in the table product
print laptop.manufacturer_id
>>> 1
# the following returns the value for the column id in the table manufacturer
print laptop.manufacturer.id
>>> 1
# the following returns the value for the column name in the table manufacturer
print laptop.manufacturer.name
>>> Acme
# the following returns the value for the column manufacturer in the table product
print keyboard.manufacturer_id
>>> None
# the following returns the value for the column id in the table manufacturer
print keyboard.manufacturer.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

The last one throws an error, because the keyboard is a no name product and it isn't associated with a manufacturer.

The above two answers are completely correct and my example is intended to be an extended explanation and to pinpoint some pitfalls that may happen in certain cases.